VS2022 - c# installer will not create regentry
So I have a simple C# program - I want/require an MSI file
And I need the application to load/run at startup so it can live in the tray.
What is it? It is an internal company tool that I need our IT group to install on all new machines for our engineering group. The IT Group requires an MSI to do this.
I can create a batch file with a reg file to make this happen
But - I need to do this from the MSI file I have created using VS2022
In VS2022 - I can right click on the installer project and choose: "View Registery" - and I can see the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, I see an entry called:  MYAPP_RUN, with a string value of "[TARGETDIR]\MYAPP.EXE" - so I believe I have this setup correctly in the VS2022 installer project.
I then run the Installer - it creates both a setup.exe and an MSI - why both? I have no idea.
When I run the MSI file (or the SetupExe) - my app is installed, I can delete the app and re-install. The app and directory is created as expected, but when I check for the REG KEY in regedit it is not present.
This does not help:
Visual Studio Installer 2022 doesn't produce registry keys
This is close - but does not help.
create an installer who executes .reg file

I didn't know VS still had its own Installer project.  I use the WIX toolset -- via the Heatwave extension. Very easy to add/query registry settings.

After running your installer, check the following registry location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (note the extra WOW6432Node subkey). Do you find your expected registry value there? If so, your installer is running in 32-bit mode and registry redirection is being applied. If that's the case I'll add an answer to explain more about what's going on.

Yep, that is it.

Hi, @user3696153 May I know if you get any chance to check the answer? I am able to see the registry string value after setting x64  in  the picture's option below.

actually i am giving up that did not work.

Can you provide more details? What does it mean did not work? Not  find the key in the registry or in Wow6432node? Please check if your vdproject  file item  is :  "TargetPlatform" = "3:1"

Simply put - I spent well over a day on it fighting the nonsense. I got the INNO_SETUP application and solved the problem in about 30 minutes... I have a usable installer and I need to move on. IMHM - the installer tool in VS is horribly complex when you try to do something really simple.

The project is 32bit by default, so the registry is redirected to wow6432node.
Set x64 target platform for MSI setup project.

